# How can I save a list to a file then read the items back into a ListBox?

Tags: c#, list, io

I am attempting to save a simple list to a file without using Serialize. Is this possible?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<string> _testList = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _add = 0;
        string _addString ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            _add =+ i;
            _addString = Convert.ToString(_add);
            _testList.Add(_addString);
        }

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedList.txt", true);

        foreach (string s in _testList)
            tw.WriteLine(s);

        tw.Close();


        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("SavedList.txt");
        // Read the data to the end of the stream.
        listBox1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // Close the text stream reader.
        streamReader.Close();
        // Close the file stream.
        //fileStream.Close();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

This emits no errors, however it does nothing.

I will use Serialize if necessary, however the suspicion is that is not necessary. Is it?

Comment: Is the file being generated or is it not being written at all?  If you can find the file, I suspect the problem is here `listBox1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();` and you are just having issues reading the file and putting it into your ListBox. You should be putting the string values back into your List<string> then adding them to ListBox.Items.

Comment: I copied your code into a blank console program and it worked just fine. Breakpoint your way through the code to see if anything jumps out as odd.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  I'll pre-pend file name with more location information to see if that helps.  Also I'll read back into list prior to listBox update.

Comment: Your comments led to solution.  SOLVED.  Listbox refresh issue.                               listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            listBox1.DataSource = _testList;
            listBox1.EndUpdate();

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `File` Class to facilitate this.

```
        File.WriteAllLines("SavedList.txt", _testList.ToArray());
```

To read it back you can then use:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("SavedList.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. It is merely a different way to write a sequence to the disk.

Comment: This is wrong. Adding the text to `listBox1.Text` is not going to work. It needs to go in `listbox1.Items`.

Comment: he asked "I am attempting to save a simple list to a file without using Serialize. Is this possible?" I gave him a way to do it.

Comment: He was already doing that. :) I am going to edit the question title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: @eddie_cat i realized my mistake as soon as i posted it, i was editing when your comment was posted. Thanks for catching that tho.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that the `Text` field of `ListBox`
doesn't work like that.

change:

```
listBox1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

to:

```
foreach(string s in streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[]{"\r\n"}))//!!!the end of line characters may differ depending on your system!!!
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

the Text field holds the currently selected text . it is not for adding items to the list.

Comment: Splitting by `Environment.NewLine` will cover the correct line endings depending on the system.